# Servlet specification for singleton servlet object

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, java-ee-5

For servlets not implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, if the
service method has been defined with the synchronized keyword, the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach (excerpt from Java™ Servlet Specification Version 2.5)

So, it's not SingleThreadModel, but specification say about instance pool approach? Normally, if we dont't describe the servlet for SingleThreadModel, only one instance would be created. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you quoted is not quite clear, but in my interpretation it wants to say the following:

If a Servlet does not implement `SingleThreadModel` but has a synchronized `service` method (or synchronized `HttpServlet#doGet` etc. methods) then the servlet container will **not** use a instance pool for the servlet.
The requests will simply be serialized through thread synchronization and performance will be bad for concurrent requests.

Comment: Why serlet container use instance pool for only one instance?

Comment: @Erdal76t As I stated in my answer I think that for the described case the container does **not** use a instance pool at all.

Comment: No you didn't get me wrong. I ask again. If a Servlet does not implement SingleThreadModel and has not a synchronized service method, servlet container use an instance pool. But Why serlet container use instance pool for only one instance?

Comment: @Erdal76t I see nothing in the quote which suggests that a pool is used for such a servlet.

Comment: I meant that servlet containers always use "pooling approach" for singleton servlet instance except not defined synchronized service method or implementing SingleThreadModel. Maybe it's occured behind the scenes.

Comment: well, what is the "servlet pool" mentioned in here?

Comment: @Erdal76t It's where a single instance of a servlet is put, and every request will use it to perform their duties. The alternative would be to create a new servlet instance for every request, but this would be bad for performance. This is also why a servlet can't keep state. If you have 5 requests using the same instance, you can't trust that the state isn't corrupted by the other requests.

Comment: Servlet specification says that Container uses instance pooling for singleton servlet isntance. Please read correctly. it's not about SingleThreadModel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the whole of **§2.3.3.1 Multithreading Issues** in the servlet specification (which has been there since at least Servlet 2.2, and probably earlier) to get the complete context of this sentence.

A container may choose to create a pool of servlet instances that have implemented [javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) in order to improve concurrency. Then each thread handling a request directed to this servlet can execute it's own servlet instance (possibly acquired from a pool) instead of blocking until an earlier request has been completed.

The container will not use this mechanism if the developer simply chooses to `synchronize` the `service` or related method.

To answer your question explicitly:

> an instance pool will ***never*** be used for servlets that do not implement `SingleThreadModel`. Therefore these types of servlet will always be a singleton.

It's all moot though because `SingleThreadModel` has been deprecated since Servlet 2.4.

Comment: Please read my quote from the spec 2.5. Read carefully. "For servlets not implementing the SingleThreadModel interface" and "if the service method has been defined with the synchronized keyword, the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach". This means that otherwise Servlet container uses the pool for single instance or many instance behind the scenes.

Comment: I read the original document. Only `SingleThreadModel` servlets will (potentially) be pooled.

Comment: 2.3.3.1 Multithreading Issues // 
For servlets not implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, if the service method (or methods such as doGet or doPost which are dispatched to the servicemethod of the HttpServlet abstract class) has been defined with the synchronized keyword, the servlet container cannot use the instance pool approach, but must
serialize requests through it.